# Change permission of all files with specific extension in a folder and subfolders using CMD

Tags: cmd, permissions, pyc, icacls, cacls

How to change permission of all files with extension `.pyc` in a folder and its sub-folder?

individually it will be like this:

```
c:\folder1> cacls *.pyc /P everyone:F
c:\folder1\a> cacls *.pyc /P everyone:F
c:\folder1\b> cacls *.pyc /P everyone:F
```

and so on.

Comment: Why wouldn't you read help first. `icacls /?` where it answers your question.

Comment: /? is very complex to understand anything

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code:

> icacls filename /grant everyone:F /T

**/T** works for me.